# I want to utilize HDFS File Browse feature in my HUE application. I don't know where to start

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue

I want to do something similar to the File Browse implementation used in Hive for uploading data in my HUE application. I don't know where to start. My requirement is

1. Display a file browse icon
2. On click, open HDFS file system and let user chose a folder or a file into something like a modal (like Windows Select).
3. Use the selected folder or file in my application.

So far,
1. I was able to display file icon and when I click on it, it takes to a completely new HDFS file browse page. But I need it in a modal.
2. Then, I tried a different approach. The following code opens up a modal but the content displayed in it is gibberish and I can't make any sense.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="/filebrowser/view=/user/hive/warehouse/customers">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

can someone please help me out on this? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: what exactly is this href href="/filebrowser/view=/user/hive/warehouse/customers" going to return?

Comment: it is going to return my Hadoop File system structure. all files and folders on my HDFS.

Comment: Hue already supports it from the metastore app, e.g. you can upload data and create a table or load it to an existing table arealdy, e.g. http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-create-hive-tables-with-headers-and/ and http://gethue.com/bay-area-bike-share-data-analysis-with-spark-notebook-part-2/